# Call a Sub with a String

Tags: excel, vba, string

I want to call a different sub depending on the value of `i`.

For example, if `i = 1` call `sale_call1` and if `i = 2` call `sale_call2`.

```
Private Sub test_Click()
    Dim i As String
    Dim pro As String

    i = Me.tb1.Value
    pro = "sale_call" + i

    If i = "1" Then
        Call pro
    Else
        Call pro
    End If
End Sub

Sub sale_call1()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub

Sub sale_call2()
    MsgBox "goodbye"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 25):

Try this

Replace `Call pro` with `Application.Run pro`

Example

```
Private Sub test_Click()
    Dim i As String
    Dim pro As String

    i = 1
    pro = "sale_call" + i

    '~~> This will run sale_call1
    Application.Run pro

    i = 2
    pro = "sale_call" + i

    '~~> This will run sale_call2
    Application.Run pro
End Sub

Sub sale_call1()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub

Sub sale_call2()
    MsgBox "goodbye"
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

If your code is not in a module but in a Userform or Sheet Code area then `Application.Run` will not work till the time `sale_call1` or `sale_call2` is not placed in a module. If you do not wish to move them to a module then you will have to use `CallByName`. Check Excel's inbuilt help on this function. Here is an example which assumes that the code is in `Userform1`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As String
    Dim pro As String

    i = 1
    pro = "sale_call" + i

    '~~> This will run sale_call1
    CallByName UserForm1, pro, VbMethod

    i = 2
    pro = "sale_call" + i

    '~~> This will run sale_call2
    CallByName UserForm1, pro, VbMethod
End Sub

Sub sale_call1()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub

Sub sale_call2()
    MsgBox "goodbye"
End Sub
```

Comment: Where have you pasted the code. I tested the code before posting it :) Ensure that the Sub `sale_call1` and `sale_call2` are placed in a module.

Answer (score 2):

Just add as prefix the workbook name where the macro is hosted.
Like when doing a formula in a cell:

```
Application.Run "WorkbookNameAsString.app_ext!MacroName"
```

Answer (score -1):

VBA uses '&' for concatenation;

Incorrect:

```
pro = "sale_call" + i
```

Corrected:

```
pro = "sale_call" & i
```

I hope it helps.