# VBA Call Method based on a string value

Tags: vba

If I declared an array of strings, and the strings are each a Sub name, how can I call the Sub of that name without needing an `if` statement?

**Example pseudo code:**

```
Set String Array = {"sub1","sub2","sub3"}
for each String str in Array
    call str 'where str is a Sub
next str
```

I do know how to create an array and call Subs; I just don't know how to call a Sub using a string value.

Comment: I understand that you want VBA (will delete the VB.NET tag). This code is (sort of) VBA but is wrong (the declarations are wrong). Also it is not too clear what you want exactly. You want to call a sub? Well... clearer now. I understood what you want better by looking at the link provided by Oliver :)

Comment: have a look at the CallByName Function. As its name suggests, it will do what you require. ETA er, just spotted this is most likely VBA - if so, I don't think this is available to you

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969796/trying-to-call-a-sub-with-a-string-vba

Comment: Why have you added the VB.NET tag again? Do you want this to be answered in VB.NET or in VBA?

Comment: No, it is not. In VB.NET you can use some of the old VB functions (present in VBA too), although this is not a recommendable proceeding. You cannot do inversely; for example: the last tag you added to reflection doesn't make any sense (this is the name of a VB.NET a namespace and VBA does not even have namespaces!!)

Comment: @varocarbas Also in your first comment you mention it is (sort of) VBA but is wrong declarations ...  if you see the line above the code this is Pseudo code

Comment: (I have deleted all my comments; I am intending to change a bit my behaviour with certain people not thinking exactly like I do) Let me try it again: sorry, I didn't see the pseudcocode part (looked at your editing story and, apparently, it wasn't bold at the start, when I read it); in any case, as a suggestion (if I may), I recommend you to write pseudo codes "more clearly neutral" (e.g., remove the Set bit, don't declare the type of variables as you are doing it, etc.), that is, in a way that it looks not too much as VB.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't make myself clear enough: VBA and VB.NET are pretty different and the answerers need to know which language you want the answer in. They are kind of similar for the declaration, loops, conditions, etc. but not for the functions/properties, etc.; VB.NET accepts some VB/VBA functions but this is not even a recommendable proceeding. For example, there is no equivalence (no direct one, at least) for the solution you have got in the answer below. Bear also in mind that "reflection" refers to a specific VB.NET namespace with no application to VBA. Please remove both tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Application.Run (str)
```

I just learned about this by doing something similar.  You can also pass a variable to that sub by doing:

```
Application.Run (str, "YourValue")
```