# how to write thusands of sub vba code quickly changing references

Tags: vba, excel, button, copy

I want a module in my workbook to write about a thousand combinations of the below

```
Sub trade0001open()
Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AO2").Value = 1
Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AD3").Value = _
Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AJ2").Value
Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AD4").Value = _
Sheets("Sheet8").Range("HA1").Value + 1
Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AO3").Value = 0
End Sub
Sub trade0001close()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AI3").Value = Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AI3").Value + 1                                    

Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AO3").Value = 1
Application.Wait (Now + 0.000001)
Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AO3").Value = 0
Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AO2").Value = 0
Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AI2").Value = Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AI2").Value + 1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Changing changing the cell references by a cumulator of four rows down each time. So every AO2 would become AO6 in the next every AD3 becomes AD7. Everything apart from HA1 would change so that includes AO2,AD3,AJ2,AD4,AO3 for the first sub and then that includes AI3, AO3, AO2, AI2 for the second sub.

So since my code above contains the two subs I'd like copied a thousand times - each copy will add 4 rows to each cel reference in each sub.

I am quite new to vba so I guess I am after a similar autofill function like in excel except for my code to do this quickly instead of typing thousands of times unless of course I guess somebody could suggest how to do this differently. hint hint. bare in mind I obviously want all the values pasted without a clipboard so that when those values from where they are copied change, the destination doesn't change. Which is what my above code achieves.

Then I'd like to asign each individual sub within each of the two separately to a developer button control in the spread sheet ( again asigned to change four rows down each time)

**@matteo to clarify ''well I envisioned the only way was to have 1000 trade0001open() and 1000 trade001close() possibly defined as trade0001open() , trade0002open() etc ditto close etc etc in order to right click for each one on a vba developer for control button alligned to each cell AK4 for open button and AM4 for close button so AK8 and AM8 etc etc which is long winded again and Im refraining from assuming a developer button could be alligned to each of those cells frm within vba and assigned to each of the sub at the moment. I guess one workaround might be to configure the j somehow into the sub name .''**

**matteo's reply: ''What you ask is complex to answer here, i will give you a tip to get started: use always the same macro but intercept the reference of the cell from which the call starts in order to add dinamically the 4 rows as I showed you above. You don't need 2000 macros, only 2 that are readapting themselves depending on the caller parent''**
me : ''so I guess this is more complicated than it seems if I could somehow make form button's alligned to cells to reference the j value within the 2 macros without need for making thousands of  sub macros. As far as I know form buttons in excel can only reference sub functions without reference and not UDFs or anything else or even cell references although I probably am wrong about this. ''

a form button to call the sub based on a cell's reference that is what I need right?

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/843078-loop-visual-basic-applications-sub-call-form-button-each-nth-row-based-cell-value-row-reference.html#post4105072

I don't know for the life of me where to begin [Trying to call a Sub with a String - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969796/trying-to-call-a-sub-with-a-string-vba)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make every string dinamically redefined and loop 1000 times the same macro. This is an example to get started:

```
For j = 1 To 1000 '<-- do this 1000 times
    '...
    Sheets("TRADEDIARY").Range("AO" & 2 + (j-1)*4).Value = 1 '<-- if j=1 then row = 2, if j=2 then row = 2+4 = 6 etc. 
    '...
Next j
```

Comment: oh ok - sounds great.. so do I do that for each sub and just adjust the reference. But when I right clikc each of the thousand developer macro buttons will they show each sub to assign to it? Essentially I am looking to label each of the 1000 or 2000 subs it will be

Comment: @Jonwhite you need to index all your hardcoded rows (2,3,4 etc.) and put  the body of your macro in the For loop. Always save a copy of your workbook before to run a VBA code (not only a loop), because VBA changes are not reversible

Comment: ok sure I will definately save but I am not sure this will do  exactly what I want because I assume I need each sub named to reference them in a button. I want to run the sub at my discretion from a button but this is definately a start. :)

Comment: @Jonwhite could you please clarify a bit your question then? I think I misunderstood the part of "each macro assigned to a button"

Comment: sure - well I envisioned the only way was to have 1000 trade0001open() and 1000 trade001close() possibly defined as trade0001open() , trade0002open() etc ditto close etc etc in order to right click for each one on a vba developer for control button alligned to each cell AK4 for open button and AM4 for close button so AK8 and AM8 etc etc which is long winded again and Im refraining from assuming a developer button could be alligned to each of those cells frm within vba and assigned to each of the sub at the moment. I guess one workaround might be to configure the j somehow into the sub name ..

Comment: It is possible, but you need some code re-design. What you ask is complex to answer here, i will give you a tip to get started: use always the same macro but intercept the reference of the cell from which the call starts in order to add dinamically the 4 rows as I showed you above. You don't need 2000 macros, only 2 that are readapting themselves depending on the caller parent.

Comment: ah I see so the button could call them based on something. Sounds difficult. I guess I could paste the vba buttons ( if they're the same or attached to a unique reference for each row) and take a shortcut in making them and alligning them in vba - can anyone suggest another forum or person to go to.

Comment: my conclusion to my original  question is that I'd need a form button which has a sub macro which calls the trade0001open() and another for trade0001close(). And from those two sub's the other sub calling that sub can use a cell reference to call the part of the sub that contains that value of j AND the HA1 part. my mind is blown LOL

Comment: I could probably make a keyboard short cut to do this labour ( press down on keyboard 10 times etc etc then backspace then press 6 or 7 or 8 within vba editor) work a thousand times but it is still a pain in the ass to right click 2000 times assign macro