# How do I hotkey current sheet's VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I've had the issue of `Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` triggering every time I click on something, which I don't want, as it means I have to wait every time I click in the actual sheet. I changed the code to `Worksheet_Open`, but that means I have to click the Run button whenever I want the code to run.

So I'm looking for a way of only running the current sheet's VBA code when I want to while I'm looking at the sheet (not while I'm in the VBA Editor). Ideally I'd be able to assign it to a hotkey using `Application.OnKey`, but I can't figure out how to refer to the sheet's code itself. The only solution I've found refers to an external macro, which isn't helpful, since I'm only wanting to use the code that's already in the sheet, as I'm using different macros for each sheet in the workbook.

Comment: If you don't want it to respond to events, then why have it in the sheet's module. Move it to a standard module and assign a hotkey. Would that work?

Comment: Or add a button to the spreadsheet and attach the macro to the button. This is by far the easiest for me, as I always mis-remember which hotkey's I've assigned to which macros :)

Comment: @PeterT Are you talking about a Command Button? That would work. But this is partly just me learning to be creative with VBA, command buttons are a little too easy, though definitely effective. Also since in this case I have 3 different sheets, that would mean adding 3 buttons, then removing them before I send the excel file to the recipient. Still no big deal but I'm looking for a fully automated way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, a Form Control button (you can use an ActiveX button if you like, but the Form Control version works just fine too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a macro in a module for which you set the hot key, this macro will call the one you need:
`CallByName ActiveSheet, ActiveSheet.Name & "Macro", VbMethod`.

So you need to name the macros in the format of SheetNameMacro in each sheet.

More explanation: [Trying to call a Sub with a String - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969796/trying-to-call-a-sub-with-a-string-vba)

### Update

If your sheet names contains spaces then use this:
`CallByName ActiveSheet, Replace(ActiveSheet.Name," ","_") & "Macro", VbMethod`
and of course also replace spaces in your sheet (e.g. if your sheet called "list to delete" than macro name should be list_to_deleteMacro.

Comment: So if the sheet is named "Link to Delete" then I should name my macro "Links To DeleteMacro"? One of my sheets is named "From SuccessFactors" so I made the name of the macro "From SuccessFactorsMacro." When I use the hotkey for the module, I get:

"Run-time error '40036':

Application -defined or object-defined error"

Comment: spaces in the sheet names surely occurs problem, try to get rid of them, or use updated code

Comment: Ok yeah looks like the spaces were the issue, I don't see a way to have spaces in a macro name, so I'll just change it to an underscore. Do you know of a way to pause the macro one it's run through? The VBA editor indicates that it's running continuously.

Comment: press ctrl+break to stop it