# Call a Sub with a String - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build my code that calls a Sub with a String based on answers to this question [Trying to call a Sub with a String - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969796/trying-to-call-a-sub-with-a-string-vba) by using `Application.Run` or `CallByName` but I'm getting:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Application-defined or object-defined error

when I try Application.Run

and

> Run-time error '438':
>   Object doesn't supprot this property or method

when I try CallByName.

Calling as well called Subs are in the same sheet `Sheets("Rozpad_hodnocení")`.

I'm trying to go through all option buttons with index number in name on that sheet to find Obuttons with "ne" in name, which works. With this found index I want to call a sub with the same index number and "ne" in name.
Called subs are like this:

```
OB9Ne_Click()
OB10Ne_Click()
OB11Ne_Click()
```

I can't move my code to form or module

Here's sample of a code:

```
Sub adsf()
    Dim s As Shape
    Dim Pro As String
    For Each s In Sheets("Rozpad_hodnocení").Shapes
        If s.Type = 12 And s.Name Like "*Ne" Then
            Pro = s.Name + "_Click()"
            Application.Run Pro
            'CallByName List3, Pro, VbMethod
            'CallByName Sheets("Rozpad_hodnocení"), Pro, VbMethod
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Maybe the answer is allready in previous question, but I didn't manage to adjust my code to it.

Comment: Is `OB9Ne_Click()` public?

Comment: If it's a sheet module, you will have to use `CallByName` try removing the parentheses from the `Pro` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kyle I changed Subs to Public, @Macro Man suggested removing the parentheses from `Pro` and with combination of these it works.