# How to CALL functions with their respective variable names using FOR?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to improve my code by making it readable and concise. In module named "ModTest" and Sheet1 named "ABC", I have the following:

```
Sub Questionnaire_1()  ' ModTest
  ' do something
End Sub

Sub Questionnaire_2()  ' ModTest
  ' do something
End Sub

Sub Questionnaire_3()  ' ModTest
  ' do something
End Sub

Sub Questionnaire_4()  ' ModTest
  ' do something
End Sub

Sub Math() ' ModTest

         Dim Question As Integer 

         Question = Sheets("ABC").Range("G5").Value

         If Question = 0 Then

             ' do something

         Else
                Select Case Question

                    Case Is = 1
                        Call Questionnaire_1

                    Case Is = 2
                        Call Questionnaire_1
                        Call Questionnaire_2

                    Case Is = 3
                        Call Questionnaire_1
                        Call Questionnaire_2
                        Call Questionnaire_3

                    Case Is = 4
                        Call Questionnaire_1
                        Call Questionnaire_2
                        Call Questionnaire_3
                        Call Questionnaire_4
                 End Select
          End if
End Sub
```

However, I do not only use 4 Questionnaires, but 100. My intention is to keep the lines [*Sub Questionnaire_1* (...) *Sub Questionnaire_100*], but to improve the  *Call* function named "Variable" within the *for* command by eliminating the Select Case:

```
Sub Math()

Dim i, Question As Integer 
Dim Variable as String

Question = Sheets("ABC").Range("G5").Value

       If Question = 0 Then

         ' do something

       Else
           For i = 1 to Question

             Variable = "Questionnaire_" & i

             Call Variable
           Next i
       End if
 End Sub
```

Can anyone please help? I receive the following "VBA Compile error: Expected Sub, Function or Property”.

---

**Thinking a litte more, it was possible to get round the Select Case and Call functions by another solution that has also worked and avoided the use of 100 subs! Replace all the above code by the newly improved follow up, as:**

```
Sub Questionnaire()  ' ModTest

Dim i, f, g, Question As Integer

Question = Sheets("ABC").Range("G5").Value

    If Question = 0 Then

         ' do something

    Else

        For i = 1 To Question

           f = 18 + 2 * i
           g = 19 + 2 * i

          With Worksheets("ABC")

             .Activate
             .Range("V2").Value = i
             .Range("X2").Value = "C"
             .Range("G2").Select
               Selection.Copy
             .Range("G" & f).Select
               Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
             .Range("G3").Select
               Selection.Copy
             .Range("H" & g).Select
               Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
             .Range("X2").Value = "I"
             .Range("L5").Select
               Selection.Copy
             .Range("L" & f).Select
               Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
             .Range("L6").Select
               Selection.Copy
             .Range("M" & g).Select
               Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

          End With

        Next i
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `Variable = "Questionnaire_" & i`. You use `&` to concatenate strings and `And` as a Boolean operator.

Comment: If your aim is to improve readability and conciseness, you shouldn't be using 100 Subs to begin with. Assuming they all do pretty much the same (considering the naming) you should probably look into parameters and/or classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to call a Sub with a String - VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969796/trying-to-call-a-sub-with-a-string-vba)

Comment: @LuizVaughan - you need to use `Run` not `Call` - see @SiddharthRout's answer on the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969796/trying-to-call-a-sub-with-a-string-vba

Comment: @Chrowno Thank you. The use of Classes is indeed promising but it is a technique no so easy to grasp in the short run. I came across an interesting website by the way (https://excelmacromastery.com) while studying the Class/Parameter subject. Concerning your assumption, you are right. I updated the code. Indeed just a few things change when it is being executed from "Questionnarie_1 to 100".If you know how to implement it, I would be grateful.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Hello. That duplicate is a very good solution. It can be of a great value when the Subs are completely different from one another. Thank you for pointing me out the SiddharthRout's solution. I was not able to see it at first glance.

Comment: `Application.Run()` is your friend here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this code might work for you. Please test it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MathTest()
    ' 17 Dec 2017
    ' "Math" is a module of VBA. (For explanation, select and press F1)
    ' Its use as a procedure name may lead to unexpected results

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set Ws = Worksheets("ABC")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' this loop will not run if G5 < 1
    For i = 1 To Int(Val(Ws.Range("G5").Value))
        Questionnaire i, Ws
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub

Private Sub Questionnaire(ByVal Q As Integer, _
                          Ws As Worksheet)
    ' 17 Dec 2017

    Const WhatsThis As Long = 18

    ' in the next line, all items are Variants except 'Question'
    ' Dim i, f, g, Question As Integer
    Dim RowG As Long
    Dim i As Long

    RowG = WhatsThis + (2 * Q)

    With Ws
        .Range("V2").Value = Q
        .Range("X2").Value = "C"

        For i = 0 To 1
            .Cells(RowG + i, "G").Value = .Cells(2 + i, "G").Value
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: "Variatus", Thank you for your time. Wow, we have now three possible solutions ! I took the liberty of altering your code and adapting it to suit my needs. It was tested and the link is provided (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jRHLOD3ig1OVW27iABxxJnrr6wPOtdgP). Best wishes.

Comment: I'm glad I wasn't so far off the mark and elated that my suggestion helped. I saw there was some commotion about your edits while I was asleep. The moderators thought that your customisation of my code didn't improve on the value of my answer and disallowed your edits. This is just to let you know that I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Nice to know about that. Wishing you a great Christmas.