# How can I run several macros where the Macro name begins with a specific string of characters?

Tags: vba, excel

I've created several custom functions which I would like to Register.  Currently, I have a different procedure for which I specify the registration for each function (there's no issue with that piece).  However, the only way I know of to registering all these functions is by calling each Macro by name in another procedure like this:

```
Sub spRegisterFunctions()
 Call spRegisterCUSTOMAfunction
 Call spRegisterCUSTOMBfunction
 Call spRegisterCUSTOMCfunction
 Call spRegisterCUSTOMDfunction
End Sub
```

I'm actually looking for something more dynamic so that every time I create a new function, and it's corresponding "spRegister..." procedure, I don't have to remember to add the "Call" code to the "Sub spRegisterFunction()" procedure for that specific function.
Here's an example of what attempting to do:

```
Sub spRegisterFunctions()
 Dim mc as Macro
 For Each mc in VBProject("NameOfProject").Module("NameOfModule")
  If Left(mc.Name,10)="spRegister" then
   Call mc
  End If
 Next mc
End Sub
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to run any macro in a specific module who's name begins with "spRegister".  Obviously the code above will not work, partly because some of those objects don't even exist.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969796/trying-to-call-a-sub-with-a-string-vba

Comment: @ScottCraner:  Unfortunately this won't work because I still have to specify the different values to the "i" variable for each custom function, unless I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "Register"?  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx  See "listing all procedures in a module"

Comment: I agree with @TimWilliams on the source. I have a feeling that you may need to adjust your security settings within Excel though because I'm sure programmatically referencing the VBE like that has security issues.

Comment: So the question to ask yourself is: **are you okay with significantly decreasing security to gain a few keystrokes?**